# Proper ways to handle database record updating and creating -- object.filter update

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to manage the records in my database such that the user is able to update records in the database. Currently, my implementation checks to see if records exist in the `StateOption` table. If it does then the instance is `stateoption`. If the record does not exist, the instance is `state`.  Once the form validates, depending on the instance, it will either create a new record or update an existing record. When updating the record, I get this error:

```
Cannot assign "1": "StateOptionOutcome.stateoption" must be a "StateOption" instance.
```

I understand I need the `StateOption` instance but my form uses the `State` instance, so I'm not sure how to work around this problem. Any ideas?

views.py

```
def stateoptionoutcome(request, disease_id, state_id):
    state = get_object_or_404(State, pk=state_id)
    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)

    #instansiate treatment outcomes
    stateoptionlist = StateOption.objects.filter(partstate_id=state_id) 
    if not stateoptionlist:
        stateoption = state #pass the state instance if there is no record of outcomes
    else: 
        stateoption = stateoptionlist[0]

    if request.method == "POST":
        optionForm = SelectOptionForStateForm(request.POST, disease=disease, instance=stateoption)


        if optionForm.is_valid(): 

           #Saves user options to database
           for option_id in request.POST.getlist('relevantoption'):
               if not StateOption.objects.filter(partstate=state):
                   state_option = StateOption.objects.create(partstate=state, partoption_id=int(option_id))
               else:
                   state_option = StateOption.objects.filter(partstate=state).update(partoption=int(option_id))
```

models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
       state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
       relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
       relevantoption = models.ManyToManyField(Option, through='StateOption')

class StateOption(models.Model):
       partstate = models.ForeignKey(State)
       partoption = models.ForeignKey(Option)
       relevantoutcome = models.ManyToManyField(Outcome, through='StateOptionOutcome')

class StateOptionOutcome(models.Model):
       stateoption = models.ForeignKey(StateOption)
       relevantoutcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcome)
       outcomevalue = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: There's not enough information here for me to work out exactly what you're trying to do, but the fact that `stateoption` is sometimes a `StateOption` and sometimes a `State` is a sure sign that you're doing something wrong. There is pretty much no context in which instances of these two models will be interchangeable.

Comment: what additional information would you need? My question is exactly what you mentioned. There has to be a better way to manage the database. If the record exists in my table, I use the `stateoption` instance so that I can update the data in that table. Otherwise, I use the `state` instance so that I can create a new record. This is probably not the best way.

Comment: I simplified the code so that it may be easier to understand.